# KeyListener doesn't work, my Jframe can not recognise my keyboard

Tags: keyboard, jframe, keylistener, jtabbedpane

I dont know why my application can not detect my keyboard.
Application its a JFrame who implements SerialPortEventListener and KeyListener.
In the Jframe of my application I have 1 Tabbed Pane with 2 Panels.
When I press some buttons it doesn't work( NOTHING IN THE OUTPUT).

I will show you my code(Not all, just the most importants parts) :

## **MY CLASS:**

```
public class java_arduino_frame extends javax.swing.JFrame implements SerialPortEventListener, KeyListener {
```

## **MY KEYS FUNCTIONS**:

```
    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e){
    throw new UnsupportedOperationException("not yet");
    }

    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e){
        int keyCode;
        keyCode = e.getKeyCode();   
        System.out.println(keyCode);
    }

    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e){
     throw new UnsupportedOperationException("not yet");
    }
```

## **MY CONSTRUCTOR OF MY CLASS**:

```
  public java_arduino_frame() {


 getContentPane().setBackground( Color.LIGHT_GRAY );
 initComponents();  
 addKeyListener(this);

}
```

## THE MAIN

```
   public static void main(String args[]) {
    strong text
    java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            new java_arduino_frame().setVisible(true);
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

A `KeyListener` will only respond when the component it is registered IS focusable AND has focus, since clicking a button will cause the focus to be transferred to the button, the frame will no longer have input focus.

It's also unlikely that the frame would be able to receive keyboard focus directly either.

As a general rule of thumb, you should be using the [Key Bindings API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html) instead, which will provide you with the ability to over come the focus realated issues.

Depending on what you're doing, you might also consider using a `JTextArea` or a `JTextField` with a `DocumentListener`, assuming you want to send characters to through the serial connection. Have a look at [Listening for Changes on a Document](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/generaltext.html#doclisteners) for more details